# Invalid field:CONTACT.FULL_NAME in related list using

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I've ran into this problem recently in related list on a few of my account page layouts. I'm using sfdx to create my scratch org and to push my source to the org.

I realize its happening when I added the following to my project json file
enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts = true

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there is a bug in sfdx and salesforce. Check your project-scratch-org-def.json file
If you have the following remove it:

```
"accountSettings": {
  "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
},
```

and add this to your features section:

```
"features": ["ContactsToMultipleAccounts"]
```

This should improve the source push and fix the problem but if it doesn't You have to do a manual step
Go to your scratch org

- click Setup
- search for account settings and click
- click edit button
- un check - Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts
- Save
- Click edit again and now go back and check - Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts

This is painful process but it fixes the source push.