# Invalid field:SOLUTION.ISSUE in related list:RelatedSolutionList when deploying to scratch org

Tags: lightning, deployment, case, scratch-org

I have retrieved my entire metadata from the dev org and tried pushing it to my scratch org that I created using org shape
`sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --durationdays 2 --wait 180`

I am running into several deployment failures out of which one of them is `Invalid field:SOLUTION.ISSUE in related list:RelatedSolutionList` for all the case layouts included in the package.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it ? Going through an answer about a [similar issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341061/invalid-fieldcontact-full-name-in-related-list-using) but with account and contact, I thought I was missing out on a support setting. However in my dev as well as the scratch org, "Enable suggested solutions" is checked.

Update : I've tried modifying the settings file as below :

```
{


 "orgName": "nh_dev_org",
  "sourceOrg": "00D2v000002xxxx",
  "features": [
    "AuthorApex",
    "Knowledge",
    "Communities",
    "ServiceCloud"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "caseSettings": {
      "systemUserEmail": "support@acme.com",
      "enableSolutionCategory": true,
      "enableSolutionShortSummary": true,
      "enableSuggestedSolutions": true
    },
    "ideasSettings": {
      "enableIdeas": true
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me an error

> A scratch org was created with username test-tb6xjnbiq7zu@example.com,
> but the settings failed to deploy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're running into this known issue if you're on an Enterprise Edition org - [Aura context is not released after Aura Definition is saved](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HlRnQAK)

The issue seems to be specific to deploying Aura components and case layouts with the `Solutions` related list reference at the same time. The workaround is to

> Deploy aura components and case layouts separately.

Which obviously won't help you in the context of a source org push which will contain everything.

The easiest thing would be to remove references to the `Solution` related list in your case layouts if you're not leveraging them. It isn't supported in Lightning and has been marked as never coming on the [LEX Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lex_roadmap.htm&type=5).

[image]

Comment: I was trying to deploy this on a fresh org (trailhead playground) without any aura components in it. I did consider removing references but I was trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline where I'd push the entire org to a branch and then build scratch orgs against the branch, do new development and then merge it with master branch to automatically run tests and deploy it. 
In such a situation I would've preferred keeping the master branch as an exact copy of the dev org but it looks like there's no way out without commenting it.

Comment: what are you deploying (metadata types)? Are there any aura components in your deployment/source?   If this is lightning, the `Solutions` related list being on your page layout in your dev org isn't doing anything (it doesn't display) so it'd be best to remove it in the long run. However, if you're just testing/learning, that is annoying to have to do and would be good to confirm this is a bug/issue with deployments and `Solutions`

Comment: I was deploying everything including the objects, layouts, sharing rules etc etc. There were no Aura components in the source since the org was a freshly created trailhead playground and had no custom development on it. This is one of the other errors I have run into which doesn't make a lot of sense since these settings/objects are all retrieved from an active dev org.  For now I've fixed this one problem by removing the references.